# CSS: Why this the background animation is only working for chrome? It's not working on firefox or IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, animation

CSS: Why this the background animation is only working for chrome? It's not working on firefox or IE.

```
#lightbar{
width: 100%;
height:400px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
background:url("light.png"); 
background-size:150px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 8% 0%;
-webkit-animation: navLight 30s ; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name:navLight
animation-duration:30s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
```

my animation for chrome safari and opera.

```
@-webkit-keyframes navLight {
0%   {     background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;}  
5%   {     background-position: 15% 0%;background-size:150px;top:80px;}

15%   {     background-position: 38% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
 20%   {     background-position: 37% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);}  
 25%   {     background-position: 38% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

 30%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
 35%   {     background-position: 67% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; translateY: -5%;
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(0deg);}       
 40%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

 50% {    background-position: 89% 0%; background-size:150px;top:100px;}
 55%   {     background-position: 97% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; 
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(360deg);}   
 60%   {     background-position: 89% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;

 65%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
 70%   {     background-position: 67% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; 
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(0deg);}     
 75%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

 80%   {     background-position: 37% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
 85%   {     background-position: 37% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(360deg);}  
 90%   {     background-position: 37% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;} 

  95%   {     background-position: 20% 5%;background-size:150px;top:80px;}
   0%   {     background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); transform:     rotate(120deg);}  }
```

for IE and firefox
I know i dont need to use -ms- so why doesnt it work

```
     @keyframes navLight {
    0%   {     background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;}  
    5%   {     background-position: 15% 0%;background-size:150px;top:80px;}

     15%   {     background-position: 38% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
     20%   {     background-position: 37% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(360deg);}  
     25%   {     background-position: 38% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

     30%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
     35%   {     background-position: 67% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; translateY: -5%;
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(0deg);}       
     40%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

     50% {    background-position: 89% 0%; background-size:150px;top:100px;}
     55%   {     background-position: 97% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; 
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(360deg);}   
     60%   {     background-position: 89% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;

     65%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
     70%   {     background-position: 67% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; 
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(0deg);}     
     75%   {     background-position: 65% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}

     80%   {     background-position: 37% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;}
     85%   {     background-position: 37% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */  transform: rotate(360deg);}  
     90%   {     background-position: 37% 0%;background-size:150px;top:100px;} 

      95%   {     background-position: 20% 5%;background-size:150px;top:80px;}
       0%   {     background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size:400px; top:0px; margin-top: -20px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); transform: rotate(120deg);} 
}
```

Comment: That's only supported in chrome only till today, try using animation with jquery.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal what are you talking about? I see nothing there that is _only_ supported by Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

First off: You should try to post better questions. Your code is very big and unwieldy, and strangely formatted at that. We don't know what you are trying to accomplish, and it's hard to decipher. You should also replace your own image with a placeholder, like I did in the below snippet, and even try to add your own snippet and mention that it currently *only* works in Chrome and you are wondering why.

I have cleaned up your code (took me about ten minutes) and it can be structured further, but I removed all the repetitive comments, put in consistent spaces and tabs and make it in all easier to read. Easier still would be to declare everything on single lines, but okay.

When calling an animation, there is an easy, short-hand syntax: `animation: name duration repeat;` (theres more to that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation). I am using it in the example, and it means you only have declare one thing for every `-prefix-`. I also lined up the `animation` properties in the CSS.

A quick reminder: today you should only use the `-webkit-` prefix as all other browsers (the most recent versions of them and the most widely used ones) support unprefixed syntaxes. (Chrome even wants to get rid of prefixes altogether). Also note that you can use *exactly the same* code in both `@keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes`, so you only have to be sure of one and copy it to the other.

*The following snippet was tested on Safari 8, Firefox 39.0*

```css
@-webkit-keyframes navLight {
    00% { background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; }  
    05% { background-position: 15% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 80px; }
    15% { background-position: 38% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    20% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }  
    25% { background-position: 38% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    30% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    35% { background-position: 67% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }       
    40% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top:100px; }
    50% { background-position: 89% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    55% { background-position: 97% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }   
    60% { background-position: 89% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    65% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    70% { background-position: 67% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }     
    75% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    80% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    85% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  transform: rotate(360deg); }  
    90% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; } 
    95% { background-position: 20% 5%; background-size: 150px; top: 80px; }
    100% { background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); transform: rotate(120deg); }
}

@keyframes navLight {
    00% { background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; }  
    05% { background-position: 15% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 80px; }
    15% { background-position: 38% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    20% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }  
    25% { background-position: 38% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    30% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    35% { background-position: 67% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }       
    40% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top:100px; }
    50% { background-position: 89% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    55% { background-position: 97% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }   
    60% { background-position: 89% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    65% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    70% { background-position: 67% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }     
    75% { background-position: 65% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    80% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; }
    85% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  transform: rotate(360deg); }  
    90% { background-position: 37% 0%; background-size: 150px; top: 100px; } 
    95% { background-position: 20% 5%; background-size: 150px; top: 80px; }
    100% { background-position: 7.5% 0%; background-size: 400px; top: 0px; margin-top: -20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); transform: rotate(120deg); }
}

#lightbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    background:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350×250&w=350&h=250"); 
    background-size:150px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 8% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: navLight 30s infinite;
            animation: navLight 30s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="lightbar"></div>
```

Comment: @misterManSam true, I included them because I thought it would be more complete (as in: there are `-ms-transforms` in the `@keyframes`), but I did, however, mention that `-ms-` and `-moz-` are usually not used as prefixes anymore. Anyway, edited.

Comment: @MisterManSam arrgghh. You're right but there's so many mentions to clean up here... Gimme a mo', will be done in a minute. [Edit: Done].